# whileループでプログラムを任意の数だけ実行したい場合、どうすればいいでしょうか？

Tags: python

以下のプログラムを無条件に5回実行したいので、以下のようにwhileループを使って実行してみました。
しかし、5回で終わることなく、ずっと繰り返し実行されてしまいます。どうすれば5回のみのループにすることができますか？

コードは以下の通りです。

```
qs=["What is your name?",
    "What is your favorite",
    "What is your queset?"]
c=["trump","USA"]


i=0
while i<5:  
    a=input(qs)

    if a=="president":
        d=input(c)    
        if d=="handsum":
            print("great")
        else:
            print("you are fired")
    else: 
        print("bye")

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i += 1`が(`while`文と同一インデントであるため)`while`ループの外にあるように見えます。そのため、`i`が変化せず、無限ループになっていると思います。

`i += 1`を`while`ループの内側に配置すれば期待通りに動作すると思います。

Comment: 内側に配置しましたが、結果は変わりません。。

Comment: 先ほど、terminalを再起動して再び実行したらうまくいきました！恐らくうまく保存されていなかったのかもしれません。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

今回は while で実装してみたとのことですが、通常このようなループは for で実装すると `i = 0` の初期化や `i += 1` のインクリメントでミスをすることが無くなります。

```
for i in range(5):
    a=input(qs)

    if a=="president":
        d=input(c)    
        if d=="handsum":
            print("great")
        else:
            print("you are fired")
    else: 
        print("bye")
```